# Selenium (Java): Retrieve value from disabled input text field

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, selenium

I am trying to retrieve a value from an input field with Selenium in Java. Here is the relevant HTML code:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm " id="NameInputID" type="text" maxlength="16" name="NameInput" value="TheValueWanted" readonly="">
```

I have tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("NameInputID")).getText();
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.id("NameInputID")).getAttribute("value");
```

None of them returned with the value(blank text). How should i deal with this?

Thanks!

Comment: any exception or something blank text ?

Comment: Blank text. No exception.

Comment: Try JavaScript executor document.getElementById("NameInputID").innerHTML

Comment: Could you please specify the exact syntax it is supposed to be written? I am not familiar with javascript executor.

Comment: try this one `JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  String value = je.executeScript("return document.getElementById('NameInputID').getAttribute('value');").toString();` and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try via `JavascriptExecutor` :

```
Thread.sleep(3) // add a pause to wait until value of the element will be rendered
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String script = "return document.getElementById('NameInputID').getAttribute('value');");
String value = je.executeScript(script);
```

Comment: So I guess there is an additional ( in the script line, because it ends with one without a pair. Anyway now it came back with an exception saying that org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: document.getElementsById is not a function

Comment: I have in the code `getElement` not `getElements`, please try my code one more time

Comment: It came back with an empty line.

Comment: Then try to add a pause before you execute a script. Make sure, that element has value you want to get.

Comment: This did the job. Thanks!

Comment: @MilanSz. happy to hear it! So the pause helped? Like in my edited code? I'm asking for the future readers

Comment: It seems that the pause helped, although I am uncertain why. Probably because it is only step among several and the script wanted to execute on a not yet loaded form.

Comment: Could you please also try `WebDriverWait` instead of `Thread.sleep(3)`? I have added in the answer

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work. The returned value was blank, empty. I used the piece of code you added.

Comment: Ok thank you for feedback, I'll rollback my answer to the working one. It is for the future readers

Comment: It is interesting, because at first thought, webdriverWait was a good idea. Perhaps it isn't about the element being visible, but the value not being present just yet. Anyway, thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared to extract the *value from an input field* i.e. **TheValueWanted** you need to be more specific with your [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) and you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be visisble* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  String myText = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input.form-control.input-sm#NameInputID"))).getAttribute("value");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  String myText = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control input-sm' and @id='NameInputID']"))).getAttribute("value");
  ```

Comment: It came back with an empty line, unfortunately.

Comment: @MilanSz. Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: It came back with the following exception, with both: `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //input[@class='form-control input-sm' and @id='NameInputID'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)`